# To be, is or was

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, past-tense, present-tense, structure

Sometimes, I make a sentence whose subject can represent something of the past and something that still exists today. Which tense should I use for the helping verb?
For instance:
Any cellphone which **(is/was)** released between 2012 and the present year has this "mute" feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time phrase in your sentence "between 2012 and the current year" clearly refers to a point in time in the past. So a past tense must be used.

Your sentence uses a passive construction which may be confusing you. Consider:

> Apple releases/released the iphone-x between 2016 and the current year.

You should decide that the correct tense to use is "released".

Comment: What if I also refer to the apple mobiles that are still released regularly in the current year?

Comment: Same.  I've edited to speak of the iphonex, which I think is the current one. (I'm not really into apple)

Comment: But, bro, I still refer to the phones that Iphone still releases regularly in the current year. Are you saying that I should still use the past in this case?

Comment: Please don't call me "bro".  The release date of a phone is a single day.  Even if it was last month or last week, or even yesterday, it is still in the past.

Comment: So sorry, then. I am Indonesian. Sometimes, we are just over friendly :) okay, then. I will use the past for such a sentence now. Thanks a lot, James.